# Programming Button OnClick Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a method run once a user clicks a button on a page. I created a sample of code to test it but it doesn't work, though it may be because I'm using MessageBox.

```
<input id="upload-button" type="button" ondblclick="@ModController.ShowBox("Message");" value="Upload"/><br />
```

Here's the method I'm invoking.

```
public static DialogResult ShowBox(string message)
{
   return MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Any idea on how I can make this function properly?

Comment: MessageBox.Show is not for asp.net

Comment: Not very sure about the answer, but i would know right away that if what you're doing is right, you would need to change the "s to '. Change **@ModController.ShowBox("Message");** to **@ModController.ShowBox('Message');**

Comment: Ahh I see, however this was a test, like if I ran a method this way on the click event, is it suppose to work properly?

Comment: and the 's are character syntax only, it gave me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if your intent is to pass a message to the client and display a dialog:

In your view, add the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowBox","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    @Html.Hidden("message", "Your file has uploaded successfully.");
    <input id="upload-button" type="submit" value="Click Me" />
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" value="Browse"/>
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowBox(string message, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        //override the message sent from the view
        message = "You did not specify a valid file to upload";
    } 
    else 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"));
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }

    System.Text.StringBuilder response = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    response.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
    response.Append(string.Format("    alert('{0}');", message));
    response.Append("    var uploader = document.getElementById('upload-button'); ");
    response.Append("    window.location.href = '/Home/Index/';");
    response.Append("</script>");

    return Content(response.ToString());
}
```

**NOTE:**
I think this approach is less than ideal.  I'm pretty sure that returning JavaScript directly like this from the controller is probably some sort of an anti-pattern.  In the least, it does not feel right, even thought it works just fine.

Comment: This would indeed work, though say I'm trying to open an OpenFileDialog on the button click, would it work just the same?

Comment: @DezmenCeoSykes I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but I modifies the code example to also handle a file upload.  Hopefully this shows you one way (and probably not the best) you can do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a Razor template.  If so, and you're using MVC, I don't think you're approaching this right.  MVC doesn't work on an event system like ASP.NET.  In MVC you make a requst to an ACtion method, usually with a URL in the form of {controller}/{action}, or something like that.

you have few options:

1. Setup a javascript event for the dblClick event, and perform an AJAX request to the server in the event handler.
2. Use @ActionLink() and style it to look like a button.

If you are using ASP.NET, there are certain POST parameters you can set before posting to the server, which will tell ASP.NET to run a certain event handler.  However, if you're using ASP.NET, I'd recommend using web forms instead of Razor.  I've never used Razor with ASP.NET myself, but I don't think the two technologies Jive very well.